# How can I update Entry without a "submit" button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, keypress, tkinter-entry

So I have `Entries` which have some values assigned to them from a CFG File. I want to modify the CFG file when the `Entry` is updated, live, without a `submit` button;

Using `<Key>` binding will work but will take only the previous value, not the current one, as the last key pressed is not taken into consideration as a value, but as a `key-press`.

For example:

```
class EntryBox:
    def __init__(self, value, option, section, grid_row, master_e):
        self.section = section
        self.option = option
        self.box = Entry(master_e)
        self.box.grid(column=0, row=grid_row)
        self.serial_no = grid_row
        self.box.insert(0, value)
        self.box.bind("<Key>", lambda event: update_cfg(event, self, self.get_value()))

    def get_value(self):
        return self.box.get()


    def update_cfg(evt, entry_box,new_value):
        global config_file
        config_file.set(entry_box.section, entry_box.option, new_value)
        print "Config file modified. "+entry_box.section+" "+entry_box.option+" "+new_value
```

If the value in the `entry` is `05R` when I click on the `entry` and press 6, it will print `Config file modified. CURRENT_MEASUREMENT_EXAMPLE_HP shunt_resistance 05R`; after I press 7, it will print `Config file modified. CURRENT_MEASUREMENT_EXAMPLE_HP shunt_resistance 0R56` and so on, always with one keypress behind. The only way to live update it after the value has been changed is to press the `TAB` or `arrow` buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either

- `FocusOut`
- `tab` or `enter` Key
- `KeyRelease`

bindings to achieve that.

Also validation functions can help as they have previous and new values available. Please read the [docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/entry-validation.html) for more information on that matter.

It is IMHO the most "pythonic" / "tkinter" way of achieving what is a "check and submit" functionality.

*Edit*

As stated by OP, binding `focusout` could lead to problems here an example how it does indeed work:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import sys

def focus_out_event(event):
    print >> sys.stderr, "Focus-Out   event called with args: %s"%event
    print >> sys.stderr, "Entry Widget Content:               %s"%event.widget.get()
def key_release_event(event):
    print >> sys.stderr, "Key-Release event called with args: %s"%event
    print >> sys.stderr, "Entry Widget Content:               %s"%event.widget.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
    entry1.bind("", key_release_event)
    entry1.bind("", focus_out_event)
    entry1.grid()

    entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
    entry2.bind("", key_release_event)
    entry2.bind("", focus_out_event)
    entry2.grid()

    root.mainloop()
```

Test:
- enter text ("asd") to entry1
- click into entry2

The last line of output is from changing to screenshot (event that fired a `focusout`)

[image: Test Result]

Comment: Key-release is the most appropriate for my project as focus-out does not save when you click on another widget.

Answer (score 1):

You have this `key-press` in `event.char` so you can add it to text.

Answer (score 0):

I decided that `<Key>` was not the right option in my case and instead used `<FocusOut>`. This way, if you either change the value using the mouse or keyboard `TAB`, on focus out it will update it.